# How to add the same childByAutoID under multiple structures in Firebase using Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To create a new value, I use...

```
Database.database().reference().child("checklists").childByAutoId().setValue(["title":title,"imageUrl":imageUrl])
```

How can I take that .childByAutoId value created and set it under another structure like below?

[image]

I manually created the value using...

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("checklists").childByAutoId().setValue(["listID":"-Lm21a-rDc6qBPcfpVUw"])
```

How can I do it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `childByAutoId()` it returns a `DatabaseReference` to the new location. On that reference you can either write a value, or for example get its key. With the latter you can then write the same key in another location (either as the key of a node, or its value).

So something like:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("checklists").childByAutoId()
ref.setValue(["title":title,"imageUrl":imageUrl])

Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("checklists")
                               .childByAutoId().setValue(["listID":ref.key])
```

You can also use that key, in case you want another node with the same key:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("checklists")
                               .child(ref.key).setValue("yay!")
```